# How to send a data from electron to a react component in renderer page?

Tags: reactjs, electron

this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56624125/mainwindow-webcontents-send-not-received-by-ipcrenderer-on-function) explains how to use `mainWindow.webContents.send` [function](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents) to send a data "submitted-form" from electron to "inside" rendered page using `.html` and javascript.

The problem is: this cannot work in React. My app doesn't even recognize the `ipcRenderer` nor `electron` as a thing inside `app.tsx` (main root component).

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args

server side:

```
const mainWindow = createWindow('main', {
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
    minWidth: 1366,
    minHeight: 768,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

if (isProd) {
    await mainWindow.loadURL('app://./home.html')
} else {
    const port = process.argv[2]
    await mainWindow.loadURL(`http://localhost:${port}/home`)
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}

mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
   mainWindow.webContents.send('submitted-form', "hello")
})
```

app.tsx:

```
// error since electron is not available within app.tsx
// electron requires 'fs' modules which client-side doesn't have
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron")

class _app extends React.Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)
  }

 componentDidMount() {
    ipcRenderer.on("submitted-form", function (event, data) {
      console.log("received data", data)
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you didn't make it.

The way I pass information between the main and renderer is the following:

For the main.js (main Electron Process)

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

const ProductService = require('./services/product.service');

const productService = new ProductService();

/*This "service" is some "promise" data from sequelize, just keep in mind 
the data here is a promise*/
async function getProducts() {
  const products = await productService.getAllProducts();
  return products
}

function mainWindow() {
    const mainWin = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1000,
        height: 800,
        webPreferences: {
          preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    })

    mainWin.loadFile('./public/index.html');
    mainWin.loadURL('http://localhost:3000')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    /* Here is where you send the message which you have to recive from 
       your preload file, the first arg is the name by which you will 
       identify it and the second is the message itself */
    ipcMain.handle('products', getProducts);
    mainWindow()
    app.on('activate', function () {
      if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) mainWindow()
    })
  })
```

Inside the preload file you should receive it like this:

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer} = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('Products', {
    products: () => ipcRenderer.invoke('products').then(result => result)
})
```

At the end in the component you want to render the information you need to receive the information like this:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
        /* These are the names that you into the preload file */
        window.Products.products()
        .then(result => {
            setRows(result)})
}, [])
```

Comment: I forgot to close this thread. Yes, I did made it. I use `ipcRenderer.sendSync('some-event', msg)` on the "server/preload" side of the electron app and `ipcMain.on('some-event', (event, msg) => {})` on the "renderer/react" side. My solution doesn't use `contextBridge` at all. I'll give your solution solution a shot tho

Comment: My solution and example ( I add websocket into the mix too) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74683535/how-to-implement-websocket-client-in-electron-next-js-react

Comment: Sure, there are so many ways to get the data through, well done.