# How to implement websocket client in Electron (Next.js/React)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, electron

I have a working websocket server. I use a websocket as client in web browser/react before, but I'm unable to use Websocket inside electron app since WebSocket depends on browser's compatibility and for some reason, this feature is unavailable in Electron.

[I use nextron (nextjs/react + electron) boilerplate.](https://github.com/saltyshiomix/nextron)

`yarn create nextron-app MY_APP --example with-typescript-material-ui`

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import { theme } from '../lib/theme';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';

export default function (props: AppProps) {
  const { Component, pageProps } = props;

  // where to put ws here ? this placement generates an error
  const ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.100.8:8081/")
  console.log("file: _app.tsx:11 ~ ws", ws)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
      </Head>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it can't be done. Electron blocks any attempt to use websocket inside the client (React). The only solution so far I use is to convert websocket messages and events into `ipcRenderer`(https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer)

the process is fairly simple:
React receives an event and calls the IPCRenderer on the client, The IPCRenderer receive an event in the renderer (node.js) and call upon the `ws` or the websocket in the node.js

**Sending:**

```
React -> IPC -> Node.js -> websocket -> Websocket Server (main server)
```

**Receiving:**

```
Websocket Server (main server) -> websocket -> Node.js -> IPC -> React
```

I use the `ws` module fro node.js from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws)

I hope this can help someone or myself in the future

**If you want to send/broadcast an event to websocket**

```
// in the client side usually the root component, or in my case _app.tsx:
import electron from 'electron'
const ipcRenderer = electron.ipcRenderer

class _app extends React.Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props: any) {...}
  componentDidMount() {...}

  // this will send a message for a button click
  handleClick(msg: string) {
      // reply will be true if it succeed
      let reply = ipcRenderer.sendSync('some-event', msg)
  }
}
```

later in the main window app.js:

```
import { app, ipcMain } from 'electron'
import WebSocket from 'ws'

// connect with ws
let ws = new WebSocket(`ws://${YOUR_WS_SERVER_IP}:${YOUR_WS_PORT}/`)

// find the electron main window, mine's in background.ts
const mainWindow = createWindow('main', {
    width: 1366,
    height: 768,
    minWidth: 1366,
    minHeight: 768
})

// .... some electron code here ....

// when ipcMain receive an event named 'some-event'
ipcMain.on('some-event', (event, msg) => {
  ws.send(msg) // send message using websocket here
  event.returnValue = true // give a return value true 
})
```

**If you want to handle an event received from websocket**

```
import { app, ipcMain } from 'electron'
import WebSocket from 'ws'

// connect with ws
let ws = new WebSocket(`ws://${YOUR_WS_SERVER_IP}:${YOUR_WS_PORT}/`)

// find the electron main window, mine's in background.ts
const mainWindow = createWindow('main', {
  width: 1366,
  height: 768,
  minWidth: 1366,
  minHeight: 768
})

ws.on("message", (message: any) => {
   var str = message.toString()
   console.log("Message received: ", str)
   
   mainWindow.webContents.send('some-event', str)
})
```

on the react component (App.tsx) :

```
// in the client side usually the root component, or in my case _app.tsx:
import electron from 'electron'
const ipcRenderer = electron.ipcRenderer

class _app extends React.Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props: any) {
      super(props)
      // I put this since I use class based component. 
      // a functional ones won't need this
      this.handleIpc = this.handleIpc.bind(this)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      this.handleIpc() // to make sure the ipcRenderer manipulate the component state AFTER the whole component was loaded first
  }

  handleIpc() {
    var self = this
    ipcRenderer.on("some-event", function (e, data) {
       console.log("Message received: ", data)
    })
  }
}
```